# What is my problems with DatePickerCellEditor()?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, jtable, tablecelleditor

I use DatePickerCellEditor in JTable columns.
Now when i want to get value and convert it to date get some exceptions in this part:
  `Date date = new Date(valueAt);`.

And get this Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:617)
    at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:274)
```

Here is my code.

```
public class DateColumnDemo {

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DateColumnDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{{"1", new Date()}, {"2", new 
    Date()}}, new Object[]{"Id", "Time"});
    TableColumn dateColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    dateColumn.setCellEditor(new DatePickerCellEditor());
    JPanel jp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    JButton jb = new JButton("Button");
    jb.addActionListener(e -> {
        String valueAt = table.getValueAt(0, 1).toString();
        try {

            Date date = new Date(valueAt);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 1));
        System.out.println(table.getValueAt(1, 1));
    });
    jp.add(scrollPane);
    jp.add(jb);
    frame.add(jp);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
            createAndShowGUI();
   }
}
```

Please help me.
thanks

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, You 're right . I edit.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Thanks for your help. it works now. ` table.getValueAt(0, 1).getClass() `

Comment: You can see from the table model that it holds `Date` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JTable holds Date objects in the first column:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{
            {"1", new Date()}, 
            {"2", new Date()}
        }, new Object[]{"Id", "Time"});
```

And so this:

```
String valueAt = table.getValueAt(0, 1).toString();
```

followed by

```
Date date = new Date(valueAt);
```

Where you call `toString()` and then creating a new Date with the String representation makes no sense. Instead cast the Object to `java.util.Date`.

```
Date date = (Date) table.getValueAt(0, 1);
```

Although you may wish to first do a `null` check before using such objects.